# Electoral Data analysis - OCR is not working

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm working on analysis voters data. Data is in scanned pdf and for analysis I need to convert them. I was able to do if the document in text pdf ( using pyPDF2). However, there are few documents where the voterlist is scanned copy, trying to perform OCR, however output is weird.

Below is my code:

```
import os
import PyPDF2
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import fitz
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

directory = r'C:\Users\AUS\Downloads\Electoral_roll'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        src_file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        src_file = open(src_file_path,'rb')
        pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(src_file)
        num_pg = pdfreader.getNumPages()

        start_pno = 2
        end_pno = num_pg-1
        
        for pg in range(start_pno,end_pno):
            pageob = pdfreader.getPage(pg)
            
            pdf_data = pageob.extractText()
            
            pdf_doc = fitz.open(src_file_path)

            pdf_page = pdf_doc.load_page(pg)
            pix = pdf_page.get_pixmap()
            image = Image.frombytes("RGB",[pix.width,pix.height],pix.samples)
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image,lang='eng')
            print(text)
            

            try:
                dest_file = open('pdf_content.txt','a')
            except FileNotFoundError:
                dest_file = open('pdf_content.txt','w')

            dest_file.write(text)
            dest_file.close()
```

My PDF has scanned documents as below: (If you want to download the pdf file, you can download from [here](https://ceoaperolls.ap.gov.in/AP_Eroll_2022/Rolls) )

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

My output is as below:

[image]

I want the OCR to perform/extract the details like Name, House No, gender so I can use it for analysis.  Just for ref here is [my code](https://github.com/Tejalaps/Electorl-Data/blob/main/Voter.py) which works fine for text pdf. But I'm struggling with pdf with scanned documents.

I'm looking  for an insights or any workarounds in achieving what I was trying to do. Any insights or updated logic are much appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Hey @possum I'm not actually looking for any help. I want to get an insights on what else I could try better. Probably someone have might done in the same in past. Since tesseract and pypdf2 is not working for me, I've posted this so I could get expertise suggestions around this. Instead of marking a downvote, if you aware of this, you could give me a suggestion  on what Libraries I could use to achieve my problem statement.

Comment: You should read and understand how this place works and how to ask a good question (which it seems you have eliminated any questions now).  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This is not a discussion site nor a general help forum. It is built around a "ask a single, unambiguous question that can be definitively answered" model.  This is in the spirit that someone else with the same question or issue can find useful answers.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409384/why-are-opinion-based-questions-banned "No guesses, no opinions, no discussions, just the facts"

Comment: Are those real people and is that their personal information? Is this post a privacy violation?